# In Julia, how to compute the mean (average) between two DateTime arrays?

Tags: arrays, datetime, julia, mean

Given two DateTime arrays of equal size, my solution to find the mean between each DateTime pair in Julia is as follows:

```
using Dates
d1 = [DateTime(2000,1,1,14), DateTime(2000,1,1,15), DateTime(2000,1,2,14) + Millisecond(1)] 
d2 = [DateTime(2000,1,1,13), DateTime(2000,1,1,12), DateTime(2000,1,2,10),] 

d1 .+ map(v -> Millisecond(round(v.value * 0.5)), d2 .- d1)
```

Is this actually the best way to do it? - I find it quite convoluted ...

H.M.

P.S. For the underlying issue, see [this item at JuliaLang](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15322)

Comment: You can write: `d2 .+ (d1 .- d2) ./ 2` (note that your formula probably contained a mistake as you need `d2` not `d1` in front).

Comment: Thanks - but this does not work ... I have updated the question with an example where your solution fails; but mine, actually, also failed - I have updated it (and reversed d1 and d2 - thx for that).

Comment: `d1 .+ div.(d2.-d1, 2)` ? Or `@. d1 + (d2 - d1) ÷ 2`? The behaviour is a bit different from `round`, though. Depends on what you actually need.

Comment: Thank you for helping that newbie :-) ... I had to learn that \div<tab> creates the ÷ sign, but now I'm happy! Actually, I'll go with d1 .+ (d2 .- d1) .÷ 2 ... I think.

Comment: I proposed `/` rather than `÷` because in your original example you did not use millisecond precision. If you need precision to the millisecond then what @DNF proposes is the right approach (and as noted - you need to decide how you want to handle rounding).

Comment: @Bogumil - yes, my initial example was not sufficiently "complicated", and my question not precise enough - sorry for that. Essentially, what I need is (a) something that never throws an exception for DateTimes from now to a few years in the future; and (b) where rounding below the seconds is not relevant. So I've also learned to think a little longer about how to ask ;-) ...

Comment: @H.M.Müller  I was wondering if you could write an "answer" on the basis of these comments, so that the public can see the solution without reading through these comments?

Answer (score 1):

`d1 .+ ((d2 .- d1) .÷2)`

Where the items in d2 are after the ones in d1.